# Creating an efficient indexer for my Azure Search Service

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

My data source cannot be a single table as I need data that spans across 6 tables. For that I have created a view that does joins on these tables. 
When I use this view as data source, indexing takes a lot of times and times out. I tried increasing timeout to 40 minutes  and one more suggested change:

"disableOrderByHighWaterMarkColumn" : true

It timed-out. I also set Batch Size:1000. This time it  populated the index but failed after few hours saying "connection lost". and "thanks" to disableOrderByHighWaterMarkColumn, If I rerun indexer again it will process all the rows again.

My question is what is the best way to approach a solution to this problem.

Follow-up Question: Since I am relying on a view, I cannot have auto change tracking. I am using a high watermark column (LastUpdatedTime) to track changes in my View. I only want to keep 6 months of data in my index so I am not sure how I can do that when I am using View. I have "where CreateDateTime > dateadd(month, -6, getdate())" clause already in my View but this will not enable Indexer to delete "out-of-time-window" rows(documents) from index. How can I achieve my goals here?
Should I write a processor task to periodically query all documents using C# SDK and delete documents based on date?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear the Azure SQL Database indexer is giving you trouble. I noticed a couple of things in your question that might be worth thinking about in terms of SQL performance:

> My data source cannot be a single table as I need data that spans across 6 tables. For that I have created a view that does joins on these tables When I use this view as data source, indexing takes a lot of times and times out.

It's worth taking a look at the [query performance troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/identify-query-performance-issues) and figure out what exactly is happening in your Azure SQL database that is causing problems. Assuming you want to use change tracking support, the default query the indexer uses against the SQL database looks like this:
`SELECT * FROM c WHERE hwm_column > @hwmvalue ORDER BY hwm_column`
We frequently see issues with performance here when there isn't an index on the hwm_column or if hwm_column is computed. You can read more about [issues with the high water mark column here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers#high-water-mark-change-detection-policy).

> I tried increasing timeout to 40 minutes and one more suggested change: "disableOrderByHighWaterMarkColumn" : true It timed-out. I also set Batch Size:1000. This time it populated the index but failed after few hours saying "connection lost". and "thanks" to disableOrderByHighWaterMarkColumn, If I rerun indexer again it will process all the rows again.

`disableOrderByHighWaterMarkColumn` doesn't seem like it will work for your scenario, so I agree that you shouldn't set it. Decreasing the batch size seems to have had a positive effect, I would consider measuring the performance gain here using the troubleshooting guide referenced above

> Follow-up Question: Since I am relying on a view, I cannot have auto change tracking. I am using a high watermark column (LastUpdatedTime) to track changes in my View. I only want to keep 6 months of data in my index so I am not sure how I can do that when I am using View. I have "where CreateDateTime > dateadd(month, -6, getdate())" clause already in my View but this will not enable Indexer to delete "out-of-time-window" rows(documents) from index. How can I achieve my goals here? Should I write a processor task to periodically query all documents using C# SDK and delete documents based on date?

Instead of filtering out data that is more than 6 months old, I would consider adding [soft delete policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers#soft-delete-column-deletion-detection-policy). The challenge here is that the indexer needs to pick up rows that should be deleted. The easiest way to accomplish this might updating your application logic to add a new column to your view indicating the row should be deleted. Once the value of this column changes, the LastUpdatedTime should also be updated so it shows up in the next indexer query.
You can write your own processor task, but querying all documents in Azure Cognitive Search and paging through them may have negative performance implications on your search performance. I would recommend trying to get it working with your indexer first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matthew!

Comment: Why Azure Search does a query like select *... That is a very heavy query as it is asking to load all the table. Can't it be made to load rows in paginated way? I dont think BatchSize has any effect on the query itself.

I am going to try create an index on my high watermark column and check the performance. Thanks for suggesting that!

If I remove disableOrderByHighWaterMarkColumn = true, then it always times out.

Comment: You mean I should update the column periodically and mark it for deletion if row has CreateDateTime more than 6 months? If I remove 6 month window, query will become even bigger. 
Actually, view is anyway a non-recommended way of fetching data in my team. I was asked to use APIs to interact with the db rather than consume view directly. That is why my next step was to create and maintain index using SDK.

Comment: Azure Search does load rows in a paginated way, it executes the select * and moves through a cursor.

For the soft delete policy, I think you have the right idea of marking for deletion if CreateDateTime is more than 6 months.

If you team is recommending to use apis to interact the db, another option would be to create a flat table with a denormalized representation of your data that would have been included in the view. That way you can use integrated change tracking and avoid some of the high water mark issues you ae having

Comment: Hey Matthew, adding soft delete column looks cumbersome to me. I would have to get rid of 6 month window making my view even bigger. Also I tried creating index on LastUpdatedTime as you suggested but it threw error cause I had 6 month where condition: `The function 'getdate' yields nondeterministic results. Use a deterministic system function, or modify the user-defined function to return deterministic results`.

Comment: This is what I am thinking: Keep the View as-is with 6 month window so that my indexer only indexes relevant data. I would keep timeout to be ~4 hours. I tried doing this and it worked. Now, the problem remains for deleting older irrelevant data from index periodically. Since I would not have soft delete column in my view, I would write a script that goes through index and delete documents with CreateDateTime>6 months. This does not have to happen daily cause it is mostly the storage issue that I am trying to solve here.

Comment: I have two issues with soft column: First I will have to get rid of 6 month condition that is going to make my View query even bigger. Second I will have to write another task that updates this View. This is again equivalent to what I am thinking of doing to go through index and delete older documents, which I think is more straightforward. Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: I would avoid paging through Azure Search results, and instead query the source data to find which records need to be deleted and issuing deletes for those against the Azure Search index

Comment: Ok. Sounds great. Can the documents be group deleted?

Comment: Each row would need the soft delete value to be set correctly

Comment: I was talking about deleting documents using REST Api.

Comment: Yes, Azure Search supports batch deletes. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents for more information